# Parsing Wikia dumps into link graph

Tags: python, xml, mediawiki, wikia

I am trying to parse the xml from a wikia dump to pull out the child element and then look for the links in the text identified by [[ and ]]. So from the following sample snippet from one wiki we should get

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.6/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.6/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.6.xsd" version="0.6" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Wookieepedia</sitename>
    <base>http:///10.8.66.74/wiki/Main_Page</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.19.24</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">Media</namespace>
...
      <namespace key="1202" case="first-letter">Message Wall Greeting</namespace>
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>Brianna</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>5</id>
...
    <text xml:space="preserve" bytes="36038">{{Eras|old|featured}}
{{Youmay|the [[Echani]] [[hybrid]]|the [[Brianna (Human)|Human]]}}
{{Character
|type=Jedi
...
```

that the above would  identify that the Brianna page links to the Echani page, as well as to the "hybrid" and "Brianna (Human)" pages.

Is there a good mediawiki parsing tool for python that can spit this out?  Performance is not a major concern, since this is done offline, and these wikis are not huge.

Comment: Did you try contacting mediawiki users/devs? They might be active in chat/forums/etc. and I guess there is already some tool for doing this kind of link exploration. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't sound: use the [links API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Links) instead. There are multiple [Python clients](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python). Never do wikitext parsing on your own unless absolutely forced!

Also note that, for all wikis but the small ones, Wikia's dumps are completely broken (truncated at a random point). See also https://archive.org/details/wikia_dump_20141219 and https://github.com/Wikia/app/pull/6118#issuecomment-183633326